# Indicate the foreign key about change in data

Tags: mysql

Hi I am using foreign key reference in `table 2`. Suppose user has changed some data in the `table 1` which is referred as foreign key in `table 2`. Is there any way (or some flag) to indicate in the `table 2` that data has been changed in `table 1`. Please suggest me if this is possible or not. I am using MySql database.

Comment: Is table 1 or 2 the parent table?

Comment: Per my comment on Mr. White's answer, could you clarify what behavior you are looking for? Do you just want `table 2` to reflect the updated information, or do you want to set a value in another column of `table 2` when the corresponding row is changed in `table 1`?

Comment: @Mr.White sorry for late reply `table 1` is parent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. White's answer is correct for updating / deleting automatically, but won't "flag" updated information, which is how I interpreted the question. If you want to set the value of another "flag" column when a row in `table 1` is updated, you should look into triggers.

Note that [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm140360886894672) say:

> Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.

So setting up `table 1` with the `CASCADE` keyword will not activate any custom code in the foreign key table (`table 2`) in your example - you would have to put the trigger on `table 1` instead.

From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html), possible trigger events are:

- `INSERT` - whenever a new row is inserted (via `INSERT`, `LOAD_DATA`, `REPLACE`, etc.)
- `UPDATE` - whenever a row is modified
- `DELETE` - whenever a row is deleted (via `DELETE`, `REPLACE`, but *not* `DROP_TABLE` or `TRUNCATE_TABLE`)

and can go either `BEFORE` or `AFTER` the event. In your case, `AFTER` would be appropriate, as it will only execute if the statement triggering it was successful. The body of your trigger can be a statement or stored routine, the contents of which will of course depend on your actual table structures.

A quick search turned up a number of questions about defining triggers with this sort of behavior, which might point you in the right direction for your specific setup:

- [mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column)
- [MySQL Trigger Update with select from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048549/mysql-trigger-update-with-select-from-another-table)
- [MySQL Trigger - update table with value selected from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617308/mysql-trigger-update-table-with-value-selected-from-another-table)
- [Create Trigger MySql update or insert in another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115632/create-trigger-mysql-update-or-insert-in-another-table)

More info on using triggers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

Comment: Thanks its helps me in understanding!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of database engine you are using as well as the **referential actions** you have defined on the aforementioned tables.

These are all the types of referential constraints you can impose:

```
CASCADE
SET NULL
RESTRICT
NO ACTION 
SET DEFAULT
```

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: This works for updating / deleting automatically, but won't "flag" updated information, which it sounded to me like OP was asking for. @Ishan could you clarify?

Comment: @whrrgarbl yes you are right. To be more clear I want to indicate in `table 2` user that  `table 1` has been modified, so please modified rest of columns in `table 2` accordingly. As the calculation of rest of the columns depends on the foreign key column's value

Comment: In that case you can just create a trigger that fires `before delete` when the user tries to delete something that does not exist in the parent table.